External Linaro toolchain with Yocto Kirkstone
I have a working Yocto (Kirkstone) build that uses the default toolchain compiled as part of the build process on Ubuntu 22.04.
Now, I need to use a precompiled external toolchain. Specifically, I need to use this version:
wget https://armkeil.blob.core.windows.net/developer/Files/downloads/gnu-a/9.2-2019.12/binrel/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz

I installed the toolchain as below and ensured I could use it:
   sudo tar -C /opt -xf ./gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz
   export ARCH=arm64
   export CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-none-linux-gnu-
   ${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc --version

The Yocto manual and several blog posts say that in order to use this toolchain with my Yocto build I need to include the following in my local.conf. So I added these entries to my local.conf:
EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN = "/opt/gcc-arm-9.2-2019.12-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu"
TCLIBC = "external-linaro-toolchain"
TCMODE = "external-linaro"

However, I get the following error when I try to build my image with Yocto:
ERROR: ParseError at /home/developer/compulab-nxp-bsp/sources/poky/meta/conf/distro/defaultsetup.conf:6: Could not include required file conf/distro/include/tcmode-external-linaro.inc

I attempted to remedy this by cloning the following repository and adding it to my bblayers.conf file - however it still fails with the same error:
https://git.linaro.org/openembedded/meta-linaro.git/

I added it to bblayers like this:
BBLAYERS += "${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-linaro/meta-linaro"

meta-linaro layer.conf:
cat ../sources/meta-linaro/meta-linaro/conf/layer.conf
BBPATH .= ":${LAYERDIR}"
BBFILES += "\
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bb \
            ${LAYERDIR}/recipes-*/*/*.bbappend \
           "

BBFILE_COLLECTIONS += "linaro"
BBFILE_PATTERN_linaro := "^${LAYERDIR}/"
BBFILE_PRIORITY_linaro = "25"

LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_linaro = "kirkstone"

# do not error out on bbappends for missing recipes (mysql5)
BB_DANGLINGAPPENDS_WARNONLY = "true"

# we need meta-networking for (lib)memcached
LAYERDEPENDS_linaro = "networking-layer

How do I successfully add this specific external linaro toolchain to my Yocto build?

Use meta-arm-toolchain and read this README
